# After I installed some DVD programs and cheese, audio input doesn't work in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, webcam

I installed some DVD programs and cheese (webcam program) in 12.04 64-bit and after that the only program that recognizes my input Audio  webcam is Skype. The sound manager in the **System Settings** tool doesn't show me any devices and I can't configure input for audio and (for example) the default audio recorder doesn't work.

Comment: I installed GUVC Viewer and it recognize input audio too, then I have 2 programs Skype and GUVC that recognize input audio webcam but the sound manager on the system setting tool nor the default gnome record audio don't recognize USB WebCam input auduio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated a custom installation of my Ubuntu using Remastersys, reinstalled the custom distribution and now all is working well. I will investigate the other applications I installed in order to determine which one broke my GNOME audio control.